# Ubuntu does not shut down properly

Tags: hard-drive, shutdown

When I select 'Shut Down...' from the menu, Ubuntu shuts down but, right at the end of the shutdown, there's a very nasty Click! from the hard disk drive. This is a sound I know very well from experience. I'm concerned that if Ubuntu keeps doing this it will eventually break the hard drive. The drive is a Seagate ST31000524AS 1TB, and this is a quite new desktop computer. Is there something I can do to make Ubuntu shut the drive down more gently?

Comment: Does this click occur with other OS, or just Ubuntu ?

Comment: I didn't hear the click when shutting down with Windows 7. Mind you, I've only booted into Windows twice since I bought the computer - I much prefer Ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

Hard drive corruption. Does it make a scratching noise? I had that on my old laptop. Its when the reader of the hard drive and the disk are so close, that it comes to the point where it can scratch the disk itself. Its not with Ubuntu, its the failing hard drive.

Comment: Thanks, but it's very unlikely to be a failing drive. At the time I posted the computer was almost brand new. And as I said in the original post, it did not make the clicking noise when Windows 7 shut the machine down. If it were the drive itself, it would have made the noise whatever the OS. It seems to have stopped doing it now, anyway, so I don't know if an update has cured the problem. Or maybe I'm just going a bit deaf!